# Search for prices in PHP MySQL database

Tags: php, search

I have code that searches for cars depending on your price range:

```
$category = "SELECT * FROM tbl_listings WHERE price between '$c[0]' AND '$c[1]'";
```

For some reason, that code doesn't work perfectly. It showed me a couple cars in the right range, but also showed one that is 200,000 when I was searching between 5,000 and 20,000.

Also, what is a good way to search when some cars have a price with a dollar sign in the database and some have commas? The search form is not returning anything with a dollar sign or commas.

Comment: price with dollar sign?? commas? it means you are not using numeric datatype? that could be the problem

Answer (score 1):

Stop storing prices as strings?  A price is typically stored as one of two types:

- integer:  number of cents
- float:  dollars and cents, but be sure to set the number of decimal places to 2

One doesn't generally store prices as strings (like "$14,999.99") in the database because you can't do range queries, like the one you're trying to do now.

You also can't do arithmetic, like a query that totals the prices of a particular subset of cars.

If the data you're pulling in has formatted strings like this, use NumberFormatter::parseCurrency() to get a float from the string you're given before shoving it in the DB.  http://php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.parsecurrency.php

Comment: That makes sense. I don't even remember why I used a strong when creating the database. Can ints store dollar signs or do I need to remove them when changing the string to an int?

Comment: @user1385895 You don't store the currency symbol in the price but add the currency symbol only when displaying the price

Comment: You'll need to remove them.  I'd use the NumberFormatter class in either case, since it can handle the $ portion.  Just cast the result to an int if you don't need the decimal portion:   (int)price = NumberFormatter.parseCurrency(stringPrice);

Comment: @BenjaminCox thanks. Sounds like that's all I need to get everything to work

Comment: No problemo!  Now, would you mind scrolling up there and "accepting" my answer?  It's good Stack Overflow citizenship to reward your helpers with reputation points, which we earned when our answers are "accepted".

Answer (score 0):

Your statement about

> some cars have a price with a dollar sign in the database and some
>   have commas

makes me think the datatype in the database are not numeric datatype. This can be an issue, even provided that your `$c[0]` is correctly the lower bound and `$c[1]` is the upper bound.